# Winforms Loading Window doesn't load

Tags: c#, winforms

In my (C#) application, the user clicks a button in one window, a bunch of time-consuming calculations happen, then another window is shown. I want to put a loading window up during those time-consuming calculations so the user knows something is happening.

Most of these time-consuming calculations are not thread-safe, and much of what I've read says I should use the same thread and create a simple Winform to serve as my loading window. The problem is that the loading window doesn't load. It's a smallish window with a label that says "Loading...". When I call `LoadingWindow.Show();` the label doesn't load (there's only a white box where it should be).

I stuck some dummy code in the `Shown` event handler, but it isn't firing.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there a way to force the thread to wait until the loading window has loaded completely?

```
Code:
LoadingWindow loadingWindow = new LoadingWindow();
using (var firstDialog = new FirstDialog())
{
    var firstResult = firstDialog.ShowDialog();
    loadingWindow.Show();
    // do a bunch of time-consuming stuff
    loadingWindow.Close();
}
```

Comment: We cannot possibly help you without seeing your code.  Add the relevant code to the question.  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to refresh the display of the application that is being used for all the time-consuming calculations.

Answer (score 3):

You show the firstDialog as a dialog window when you try to show your loading screen. I suggest trying to show your loadingWindow first as a dialog window then the other. Code below.

```
LoadingWindow loadingWindow = new LoadingWindow();
using (var firstDialog = new FirstDialog())
{
    loadingWindow.ShowDialog();
    var firstResult = firstDialog.ShowDialog();
    // do a bunch of time-consuming stuff
    loadingWindow.Close();
}
```

Comment: I get the same result when I try that. If I move the `loadingWindow.ShowDialog()` outside the `using` block, it loads as expected.